# Don't log handled exceptions with ELMAH

Tags: c#, logging, exception, elmah

I am working with WebApi and ELMAH and I would like to be able to wrap some business errors into web responses for some thypes of exceptions(no logging) and have the others logged by ELMAH. Right no I have this piece of code.

```
public async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
            return await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (MyException ex)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(CustomCode)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(CustomMessage)
                };
            }          
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent("Ups! Something went wrong. Please try again or contact administrator!")
                    };
            }
        }
```

The problem is I would expect ELMAH to log only unhandled exceptions. In my case, even the exception of type MyException is being logged, although it is caught by the catch block.

Is there any config I can apply to ELMAH to make it log only unhandled eceptions ?

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH catches all exceptions thrown from your web app. If you want to filter out certain errors, you could the error filtering feature of ELMAH as described here:

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering

In your case you would probably need to add something like this to your global.asax.cs:

```
void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception.GetBaseException() is MyException)
        e.Dismiss();
}
```

Comment: ELMAH cacthes all exceptions ? It's not about unhandled exceptions only ? I would like to log unhandled exceptions only.

Comment: You could catch your own custom exceptions and return a desired response for that. Don't catch unhandled exceptions using a generic catch block (catch Exception). Let ELMAH handle that error.

Comment: I catch the generic exception that way because I would also like to return it to client as a more user friendly message.

Comment: Are you using the Elmah.Contrib.WebApi NuGet package?

Comment: Yes. Version 1.0.6.0.

Comment: Weird. The new version of that package logs everything with status code >= 400. But your version should only log unhandled exceptions.

Comment: For now I've just filtered out my base exception. Thanks.